# Does elmah handle caught exceptions as well

Tags: asp.net, .net, exception, elmah

Does [ELMAH](http://elmah.github.io/) logged exceptions even when they do not bubble up to the application?  I'd like to pop up a message when an exception occurs and still log the exception.  Currently I've been putting everything in try catch blocks and spitting out messages, but this gets tedious.

Answer (score 129):

ELMAH has been updated to support a new feature called [Signaling](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/DotNetSlackersArticle#Error_Signaling).

This allows you to handle exceptions how you want, while still logging them to ELMAH.

```
try
{
    int i = 5;
    int j = 0;
    i = i / j; //Throws exception
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MyPersonalHandlingCode(ex);
    ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex); //ELMAH Signaling
}
```

Re-throwing exceptions can be a bad practice as it makes it difficult to trace the flow of an application.  Using Signaling is a much better approach if you intended to handle the error in some fashion and simply want to document it.

Please check out this excellent guide by [DotNetSlackers on ELMAH](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/ErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlers.aspx)

Comment: is it possible to achieve that using some kind of attribute/filter? Because to put that code inside each catch it is to much i think, it would be good to have such kind of filter which would do that.

Comment: ironically that dognetslackers link leads to an unhandled error page. This has to be a troll?

Comment: here's a wayback machine link to the DotNetSlackers article: http://web.archive.org/web/20140415040316/http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/ErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlers.aspx

Answer (score 6):

A filter is the cleanest way to handle this problem. Check this solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/5936867/965935

Comment: As far as I understand a filter will not be able to catch an exception already handled in a try catch block. Check this answer here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21864117/694457).