# How to get redirected URL and content using HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

Sometimes my URL will redirect to a new page, so I want to get the URL of the new page.

Here is my code:

```
URL url = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88326/");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);

System.out.println(conn.getURL().toString());
```

The output is:

> stackoverflow.com/questions/88326/does-elmah-handle-caught-exceptions-as-well

It works well for the Stack Overflow website, but for the sears.com site, it doesn't work.

If we enter the URL blow:

```
http://www.sears.com/search=iphone
```

the output is still:

> http://www.sears.com/search=iphone

But actually, the page will redirect to:

```
http://www.sears.com/tvs-electronics-phones-all-cell-phones/s-1231477012?keyword=iphone&autoRedirect=true&viewItems=25&redirectType=CAT_REC_PRED
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The Sears link is not a HTTP redirect: `curl --head -I http://www.sears.com/search=iphone`. It probably redirects through JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually we can use HttpClient, which we can set HttpClient.followRedirect(true)
HttpClinent will handle the redirect things.

Comment: that's the best way... or you have to take redirect link in the header again and again...which is too much complicate...

Comment: care to elaborate what you did? i'm in a similar situation

Answer (score 21):

Simply call `getUrl()` on `URLConnection` instance after calling `getInputStream()`:

```
URLConnection con = new URL(url).openConnection();
System.out.println("Orignal URL: " + con.getURL());
con.connect();
System.out.println("Connected URL: " + con.getURL());
InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
System.out.println("Redirected URL: " + con.getURL());
is.close();
```

If you need to know whether the redirection happened before actually getting it's contents, here is the sample code:

```
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(url).openConnection());
con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
con.connect();
int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
System.out.println(responseCode);
String location = con.getHeaderField("Location");
System.out.println(location);
```

Comment: but still not works for "http:// www.sears.com/search=iphone", could please please help me figure out what's up?

Comment: your code works for stackoverflow.com/questions/88326/, but not for sear.com   I guess maybe sear.com is not an redirect. It is get something from server.

Comment: The Sears link is not a HTTP redirect: `curl --head -I http://www.sears.com/search=iphone`. It probably redirects through JavaScript.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I'm trying to expand this url http://skl.sh/thomasfrank11 but I get the same url when I do con.getUrl()