# Searching for code to log raw HTTP+cookies from Android HttpURLConnection

Tags: android, networking

Has anyone released code to show the full HTTP request/response headers, any intermediate redirects, and any cookie data for the Android HttpURLConnection? This would be similar to Firefox Web Console

I roughly know how to write this myself, but 1) it's a non-trivial amount of code 2) it's tricky to get this kind of code to work in all instances. So i'm interested in finding a readymade solution. I know how to tcpdump the emulator, but I'm searching for code to print this information into the Android Log class for really quick runtime debugging.

Answer (score 0):

for header fields

```
    URL url = new URL(str_url);
         HttpURLConnection conection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
         conection.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT_SOCKET);
         conection.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT_CONNECTION);
         conection.addRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
         RedirectLocations locations = new RedirectLocations();

         // here u get all header fields and properties write it in logs
         conection.getHeaderFields();
         conection.getRequestProperties();
    //      conection.getOutputStream().write(buffer);
        // download the file
         InputStream is = conection.getInputStream();

         // This is file path were a; quiz data will get saved. 

        // String file_path = context.getDir(folder,Activity.MODE_PRIVATE).getAbsolutePath();
         return unzip(is,save_file_path);
```

for redirects

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15057346/793943)

after u get response, again u ve to look for header fields

Comment: This doesn't show cookies, which are the primary item of interest for most redirect-heavy sites. Rereading my original question this may have been an unclear requirement, so I've updated the question to show that cookies are important

Comment: For that you should use CooikeManagerSync, its globle in android.

Comment: I know how to program what I want :-) However, there are many small items that would make programming+debugging this take a good amount of time. I'm asking if anyone has taken the time to build something already

Comment: many of them would have built but its according their requirement.

Comment: A decent http connection monitor code is a pretty general requirement. It's just tricky to do it properly. Any fool (myself included) can hack something together and either ignore or be ignorant of the bits that don't work

Comment: then better i suggest encription based mechanism.