# HTML anchor tag onclick to Submit form and Redirect to href link

Tags: javascript, html, forms, anchor

I'm trying to submit the form and redirect to href url specified in anchor tag href attribute.

Form:

```
<form id="myform" method="POST">
    <a href='http://www.google.com' onclick='submitResponse()'>SUBMIT</a>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
function submitResponse() {
    document.forms[0].submit(); 
}
```

But it only redirects to the link and form is not getting submitted.

I also tried this and is not working either.

```
<form id="myform" method="POST">
    <a href='#' onclick='submitResponse()'>SUBMIT</a>
</form>

function submitResponse() {
    window.location.href = "http://www.google.com" ;
    document.forms[0].submit(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read up on forms here:

[forms](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_forms.asp)

The soloution to your problem:

```
<form action="http://google.com" method="POST">
```

When you execute the form submitt and if you dont specify an url adress in the action the page will simply reload.

the only reason you get redirected is because of this:

```
 window.location.href = "http://www.google.com" ;
```

EDIT:

consider this:

```
function submitResponse() {
    $('form').submit(function(){
        $.post('http://google.com', function() {
          window.location = 'http://google.com';
        });

      });
}
```

The form gets submitted and in the success function you redirect to the desiered site.

the reason your code does not work is since the redirect does not wait for the form to submitt, it directs right away.

Comment: What should be my href attribute then?

Comment: On the ancor tag? You don't need one. If you add the url to the form action and submitt the form via script then the problem is solved

Comment: Form submits fine. But after form is submitted, it isn't redirecting to action url.

Comment: Check edits. If that does not work then try removing the post attribute on the form.

Comment: _//the reason your code does not work is since the redirect does not wait for the form to submitt, it directs right away._ - I think you misunderstood my problem. The submit works fine. But the redirect to action URL is not working.

Comment: You described this in your question "But it only redirects to the link and form is not getting submitted."

Comment: Apologizes. To be clear, after following the solution to add action attribute in form, form submission works. But redirect to action URL is not working.

Comment: Have you tried the other soloution? the one under my edits? remove the acion method on the form and just do it with jquery, look under "Edit"

Answer (score 2):

You must to read about html forms. 
To put an action for the form use action attribute

```
 <form action="http://google.com" method="POST">
```

So your code looks like this

```
<form id="myform" method="POST">
    <a href='#' onclick='submitResponse()'>SUBMIT</a>
</form>

function submitResponse() {
    document.forms[0].action = "http://www.google.com" ;
    document.forms[0].submit(); 
}
```

Comment: Sorry. This solution is not working for some reason. I added the url to form action. Form submits fine, but url isn't redirecting.

Comment: What? I don't understand you. If you need to redirect to a page AFTER the submit of the form, you have two options: AJAX or redirect then in the target page of the form

Comment: Following your solution, my form is getting submitted. But it is not redirecting to the url which I specified in the _action_ attribute of form. I need to redirect to URL after the form is submitted. Hope I'm clear this time.

Comment: So you are using another page in action attribute. Do you use php target servrside solution?

Comment: Action send the form to a Web, so if the form submit well, the redirection works. I tell you that I think that you're looking for AJAX

Comment: Not sure what am I missing. redirection isn't working. Sorry. I'm not looking for AJAX stuff.

Comment: You can't make this if you don't use Ajax or a custom target page that redirects. A normal form the redirection is the action when you submit. There's no way to go to 2 different pages

Answer (score 0):

Simply update the action attribute of the form tag:

```js
var submitResponse = function(url) {
  var form = document.getElementById('myform');
  form.action = url;
  form.submit();
};
```

```html
<form id="myform" method="POST">
  <a href='http://www.google.com' onclick='submitResponse(this.href);return false;'>SUBMIT</a>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are submitting to a URL you can simply return the HTTP response as below.

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://www.google.com
```

References:

```
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmessages.asp 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302
```

**Update**

If you are using

**ASP.Net MVC**

```
http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/4XDc110313-return-View()-vs-return-RedirectToAction()-vs-return-Redirect()-vs-return-RedirectToRoute().html

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892094/mvc-redirect-to-index-from-another-controller
```

**PHP**

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php
```

**JAVA**

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659000/java-how-to-find-the-redirected-url-of-a-url

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057329/how-to-get-redirected-url-and-content-using-httpurlconnection
```